# Object not found error while accessing the index.html page in xampp

Tags: html, xampp

I am getting the below error while I am trying to access XAMPP in Windows 8. It was working fine last week and I am not sure, what had happened. I tried for solution online, none of them seem to work,

Error:-
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22

Answer (score 0):

did you place the index.html inside the htdocs folder ?
what's the path when accessing the file in browser ?

check this resource for examples:
http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_example_htdocs.html

Comment: I did placed the index.html file inside the htdocs folder. To be precise, I have created a folder within the htdocs and placed the file. The path for accessing the file on the browser is http://localhost/xampp/TravelDestination